# How to use functions to read user input into an array? Define error?

Tags: c, arrays, function

Why are my function calls not working properly? I'm at the start of my program and I am trying to read user data into two separate arrays. One array to store a string and one for an integer and then print what was entered. This is suppose to be a group project for class but my group doesn't show up for class so I appreciate any help I receive.

I'm trying to add this bubble sort but right right define SIZE is giving me an error...

```
    #define SIZE 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]);
void output(char fullname[][25], int age[]);
int compare(int x, int y);
void bubbleSort(int fullname[],int SIZE );

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char fullname[SIZE][25];
    int age[SIZE];
    // promt user for names and ages
    input(fullname, age);
    //output unsorted names and ages
    output(fullname, age);


    return 0;
}

void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter a full name\n");
        //scanf("%[\^n]\n", fullname[i]);
        fgets (fullname[i],40, stdin);
        printf("Enter the age\n");
        scanf("%d", &age[i]);

    }
}

void output(char fullname[][25], int age[]) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%s, %d\n", fullname[i], age[i]);
}
```

Comment: `int age[SIZE]`...aren't you missing a `;` there?

Comment: your function signatures do not match

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to declare any parameters in your functions implementations, and for that matter, any prototypes. `main()` hasn't a clue what `input` and `output` look like. If you're not receiving a *rack* of warnings from this code, time to turn up your warning levels. `printf(""fullname, age"");` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Also you can't return multiple values from a function. Your compiler should already give you a lot of info about what is wrong with this code.

Comment: A function can only return one value?

Comment: @user311607 Yes, and a `void` function can't return anything at all (besides blindly `return;`). So that `void input()` with a `return anything`) shouldn't compile either.

Comment: So void isnt very useful. Ok gotcha

Comment: How do I declare a function if it's using different types of data?

Comment: It has to use the types you intend it to use. If you want to read strings, then the parameters need to be strings (pointer to array of characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be of some help

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]);
void output(char fullname[][25], int age[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char fullname[SIZE][25];
    int age[SIZE];
    input(fullname, age);
    output(fullname, age);
    return 0;
}

void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Enter a full name\n");
        scanf("%s", fullname[i]);
        printf("Enter the age\n");
        scanf("%d", &age[i]);
    }
}

void output(char fullname[][25], int age[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%s, %d\n", fullname[i], age[i]);
}
```

Comment: Wow my code really wasn't close... So this is extremely helpful. When I run it asks the user for the name but doesn't allow the user to enter the age. I have to stop the loop from looping before the input is entered. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

2 Solutions:

First, your call could be :

```
fullname = input(fullname, age);
```

In your input function, you return something, why don't you take it back?

Second, you can also try giving a pointer to fullname for your input, you are writting on the array but your modifications won't take place outside the "input" function:

the call:

```
input(&fullname, age);
```

...
the definition

```
input(char *fullname[][25], int age[]) {}
```

i don't have the pc with me to test this code right now but the idea's here.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Could you elaborate on "why don't you take it back?" comment?

Comment: In your function, you return something. If you don't return it in a variable,you won't see any changes. That's why you have to "take it back" :)

Comment: Ohh ok thats straight forward.